# SUM with IF conditions for cells containing both strings and numbers

Tags: arrays, excel, string, sum

I've got a bigger table with one column that I want to focus on, containing designation and a number. I want to simply sum the numbers that meet the criteria based on a designation.

For the simplification, I made an exercising sheet (on the pic) where I split second column into two - one string and one numeric. Since my file is quite large with many columns that would need this it would be inconvenient.

In the left column it's easy to solve the problem, it could be even easier with simple SUMIF function, but an array SUM(IF... function is, at least I think, only viable option here.

So I solved the first table with array function, but what confuses me is how to modulate the TRUE statement. Simple replacement of C:C
with
VALUE(MID(F:F;4;4))
which would format my cells to get the numbers from string does not work that way - returns zero in E12 field. F12 is just application of string to number for last cell, F10.

[THIS](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2459-excel-sum-cells-with-text-and-numbers.html) formula does not work, even adapting to different versions of the tool.

I could use VB but if possible anyhow I would like to avoid it since parts will be shared on mobile phones.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

[Left table was split, right original format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoCUZ.png)

Comment: Can you kindly clarify what you're looking to return/what's your question? What's wrong with `SumIfs()` again?

Comment: I apologizeit might not be clear enough. I have a column with both numbers and letters. I would like to sum numbers that have certain letters by them (right table in the image enclosed, formatting similar to original).

Possible solution that would split columns is shown on the left but I have many such columns in the original sheet. I just took the approach of sum(if())since I know it supports array functions. Any solution is viable, of course, but I couldn't get correct output with array function like in sktneer's example below. I will research sumproduct function (tables can't be mixed).

Answer (score 1):

The array formula which you used can be replaced by the SumIf formula like below...

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"B",C:C)
```

Also without the helper column, you can use the Sumproduct formula to achieve the desired output.
**But don't refer the whole column in the formula like in the above SumIf formula.**

Try this..

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B10="B")*MID(F1:F10,FIND(",",F1:F10)+1,255)*1)
```

Change the ranges as per your requirement but remember to make them equal in size.